# How to break function and return last value from cycle. Returned value is None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to break function using return in the if statement. I think that I don't stop the cycle and it make another cycle where isn't return. But I can't find how to solve this issue.

## This is example of input obj

```
b =  [
       {
           "id": "160407",
           "created": "2017-10-30T09:41:37.960+0000",
           "items": [
               {
                   "field": "status",
                   "fieldtype": "test",
                   "from": "10407",
                   "fromString": "Analysis",
                   "to": "4",
                   "toString": "To Do"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": "160407",
           "created": "2019-10-30T09:41:37.960+0000",
           "items": [
               {
                   "field": "status",
                   "fieldtype": "test",
                   "from": "10407",
                   "fromString": "Analysis",
                   "to": "3",
                   "toString": "In Progress"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
```

## This is code of function

```
def recursive(obj, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []

    # Check for object type and unpacked
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            # Write path for this key
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(key)

            # Check Status = in progress
            condition = 'to' in obj and '3' == obj['to']
            if condition:
                print(new_path) #Print correct value
                return new_path #None

            recursive(value, path=new_path)

    # Check for list type and unpacked
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(obj):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(i)
            recursive(item, path=new_path)

a = recursive(b) #None
```

This function should take a object and return the path to the desired value.

Comment: Is the input object really a dictionary of a list of dictionaries? Or just a list of dictionaries? Because the outer most bracket (instance of a dict) has no key

Comment: Input object is dictionary with nested lists and another dictionaries. In the function I determine the type and expand it

Comment: Your input object is incorrect, I corrected it and it works @Ilya Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, your input object is wrong, you have a dictionary at the outermost level but you are missing a key, so I will assume your object is a list like so

```
b =  [
       {
           "id": "160407",
           "created": "2017-10-30T09:41:37.960+0000",
           "items": [
               {
                   "field": "status",
                   "fieldtype": "test",
                   "from": "10407",
                   "fromString": "Analysis",
                   "to": "4",
                   "toString": "To Do"
               }
           ]
       },
       {
           "id": "160407",
           "created": "2019-10-30T09:41:37.960+0000",
           "items": [
               {
                   "field": "status",
                   "fieldtype": "test",
                   "from": "10407",
                   "fromString": "Analysis",
                   "to": "3",
                   "toString": "In Progress"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
```

To ignore the complexities of return values, it is much easier to use a global variable, assign that variable when we get to the condition and print it

```
result = []
def recursive(obj, path=None):

    global result
    if path is None:
        path = []

    # Check for object type and unpacked
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            # Write path for this key
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(key)

            # Check Status = in progress
            condition = 'to' in obj and '3' == obj['to']
            if condition:
                result = new_path
                return new_path #None

            recursive(value, path=new_path)

    # Check for list type and unpacked
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(obj):
            new_path = list(path)
            new_path.append(i)
            recursive(item, path=new_path)

recursive(b) #None
print(result)
#[1, 'items', 0, 'field']
```

Comment: Sorry, Yes, you are right about input object. But I tried to change it and got the same result https://repl.it/@IliaIeriomienko/recursive-function

Comment: Run the code  I added and it will work! https://repl.it/repls/FondSecondParameter

Comment: My bad! I was seeing the output of print statements, let me fix this! Sorry!

Comment: You've received result of print(new_path) function, and yes it shows correct value. But if you check  "a" variable (result of function) it will be None

Comment: Can you provide an example of how would  a variable `path` look like?

Comment: If we use b variable it should return list = [1, 'items', 0, 'field']

Comment: Can you explain how that output comes about! Maybe that will help me make sense of some issue in the logic!

Comment: First step is to create path variable and assign empty list. 
Then I take input object and determine the type -> object or list 
If it is object I iterate the key, write key to 'path' list and call recursive function with found item. If it is list, I do the same.

I try to loop through all the values ​​of the incoming object and get the path. When the key I need is found, I want to write down the path to this key and return it as a result.

Comment: Okay, I was able to solve it using `global` variables lol! That is the easiest way to ignore the nitty-gritties of why is return not working, which might need a rewrite of the code! @Ilya